# PHP SOAP print the xml

Tags: php

how can i print the xml of a soap call before calling it?

from what iv seen you need to alter the dorequest function, but upon doing so u get "SoapClient::__doRequest() returned non string value"

here is the code

```
public function __doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version, $one_way=0) {
var_dump( $request);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function __doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version, $one_way=0) {
    var_dump( $request);
    return parent::__doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version, $one_way);
}
```

Comment: Awsum stuff, but it does not show me all the XML, just a little and then says -... (length=822) how can i get it to display all the xml?

Comment: I assume you're using `xdebug` which is modifying the `var_dump()` function. See here: http://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#var_display_max_data

Comment: Just checked my .ini and its no activated, do u suppose it is a setting in the .ini file?

Comment: How did you check that? You're sure that you checked the correct `php.ini`? And yes, it must be referenced somewhere in the active `php.ini`. PHP's regular `var_dump()` does not limit the displayed data at all.

Comment: Youre viewing it in your browser which is interpreting the SOAP message as HTML. If you rightclick -> view source, you should see the full message.

Answer (score 0):

I have use the nuSoap call for webservice. It can be work same as soap call, i hope this is helpful for you . here is the code that i have used

```
$param = array('strUsuario' => $credentials['username'],
            'strPassword' => $credentials['password'],
    );

    $client = new nusoap_client('http://www.byte-factory.com/fidelizacion/webservice/v1/cfidelizacion.asmx?WSDL','WSDL');

    $client->setCredentials($credentials['username'], $credentials['password'], 'digest');

    $result = $client->call('IniciarSesion',  array('parameters' => $param), '', '', false, true);

    if ($client->fault) {
        echo '<h2>Fault</h2><pre>';
        print_r($result);
        echo '</pre>';
    } else { 
        $err = $client->getError(); // Check for errors
        if ($err) {
            echo '<h2>Error</h2><pre>' . $err . '</pre>'; // Display the error
        } else {
            echo '<h2>Result</h2><pre>'; // Display the result
            print_r($result['IniciarSesionResult']);
            echo '</pre>';
        }
    }
    // Display the request and response
    echo '<h2>Request</h2>';
    echo '<pre>' . htmlspecialchars($client->request, ENT_QUOTES) . '</pre>';
    echo '<h2>Response</h2>';
    echo '<pre>' . htmlspecialchars($client->response, ENT_QUOTES) . '</pre>';
    // Display the debug messages
    echo '<h2>Debug</h2>';
    echo '<pre>' . htmlspecialchars($client->debug_str, ENT_QUOTES) . '</pre>';
```